# JpaSpecificationExecutor to fiter data by group and max date value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, specifications

I am attempting to use JpaSpecificationExecutor to filter the Data with the conditions groupBy and Max Date.

Currently, to get the output I am using this query based on ranking. In my DB there are many records (hundreds of thousands of records). It is taking too long to fetch the query results. I understand that by using JpaSpecificationExecutor, we can fetch the data much quicker.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, Rank() over (Partition BY code ORDER BY dateTime DESC ) AS Rnk FROM user) pd WHERE Rnk <= 1
```

Please help me to implement same criteria in jpa specification,
Below i have attached the sample table images, Existing Table and Expected output.

**Entity Class**

```
Class User{
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String dateTime;
}
```

**Repository Interface**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>{}
```

**User Specification class**

```
public class UserSpecification implements Specification<User>{

    private final User criteria;

     public UserSpecification(User criteria) {
            this.criteria=criteria;
        }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User > root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    }
```

**Service Class**

```
public class UserService {

    pubilic List<User> findAll(){
        Specification<User> spec = new UserSpecification();
        List<User>  users = userRepository.findAll(spec);
    }
}
```

**Table Data**

[Existing sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIb35.png)

**Expected Output**
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM5xh.png)

Comment: Behind the Spring Data, in any case, there will be native queries.
Therefore it will not solve the performance problem. Perhaps JpaSpecification can make indexes on the database that may affect performance.

Comment: Can you please give the solution with jpa specification accordingly